# How to generate QR code in powerbuilder application without internet

Tags: qr-code, powerbuilder

I have a powerbuilder application developed in PB 10 and want to generate QR code but the main issue is that there is no availability of internet. Is there any free ActiveX or dll available to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google finds a number of .dll's that are capable of generating QR codes. Here is one example:

http://delphi32.blogspot.com/2013/09/quricol-20-qr-code-generator.html

To use it, all you're going to need to do is build the .dll, bundle it with your application, and make command line calls from PowerBuilder to the .dll to generate your QR codes.

Comment: Well this is the another big task to find dlls and then register and all other stuff. Would like to see if there is any free QR code font available ?